# How does one allow a generic type that is convertible to a pointer to parameterise another generic type that is convertible to a pointer?

Tags: go, generics

From the type parameters proposal, there is [a useful section](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#pointer-method-example) describing how one should define a type constraint such that a type that already implements the interface via it's pointer receivers can still be used as a type parameter, for example:

```
type ExplainedExampleGeneric[T any] interface {
    GetBool() bool
    *T // non-interface type constraint element
}

type ExplainedImpl struct{ bully bool }

func (e *ExplainedImpl) GetBool() bool { return e == nil || e.bully }

func Print[T any, PT ExplainedExampleGeneric[T]](impl T) {
    fmt.Println(PT(&impl).GetBool())
}

func main() {
    Print[ExplainedImpl](ExplainedImpl{}) // Prints: false
}
```

For my use-case, I want to use this `ExplainedExampleGeneric` as a parameter to another generic type:

```
type UncharteredGeneric[T any, U any, V ExplainedExampleGeneric[U]] interface {
    GetString() string
    GetExplainedExampleGeneric() V
    *T // non-interface type constraint element
}

type ExplainedExampleGeneric[T any] interface {
    GetBool() bool
    *T // non-interface type constraint element
}
```

This compiles, **however**, when trying to compile a function to utilise this `UncharteredGeneric` type, I get the following errors:

```
./prog.go:35:40: got 2 arguments but 3 type parameters
./prog.go:36:17: cannot convert &impl (value of type *T) to type PT
```

```
func UncharteredPrint[T any, U any, PT UncharteredGeneric[T, U]](impl T) { -> got 2 arguments but 3 type parameters
    fmt.Println(PT(&impl).GetExplainedExampleGeneric().GetBool()) -> cannot convert &impl (value of type *T) to type PT
}
```

Finally, when I try to call this function, my type is unable to be inferred [link to playground](https://go.dev/play/p/x0jbLebaf7d):

```
./prog.go:36:40: got 2 arguments but 3 type parameters
./prog.go:37:17: cannot convert &impl (value of type *T) to type PT
./prog.go:42:50: cannot infer PT (prog.go:36:37)
```

```
package main

import "fmt"

type UncharteredGeneric[T any, U any, V ExplainedExampleGeneric[U]] interface {
    GetString() string
    GetExplainedExampleGeneric() V
    *T // non-interface type constraint element
}

type ExplainedExampleGeneric[T any] interface {
    GetBool() bool
    *T // non-interface type constraint element
}

type UncharteredImpl struct{ some string }

func (e *UncharteredImpl) GetExplainedExampleGeneric() ExplainedImpl { return ExplainedImpl{} }
func (e *UncharteredImpl) GetString() string {
    if e == nil {
        return ""
    }
    return e.some
}

type ExplainedImpl struct{ bully bool }

func (e *ExplainedImpl) GetBool() bool { return e == nil || e.bully }

func Print[T any, PT ExplainedExampleGeneric[T]](impl T) {
    fmt.Println(PT(&impl).GetBool())
}

func UncharteredPrint[T any, U any, PT UncharteredGeneric[T, U]](impl T) { -> got 2 arguments but 3 type parameters
    fmt.Println(PT(&impl).GetExplainedExampleGeneric().GetBool()) -> cannot convert &impl (value of type *T) to type PT
}

func main() {
    Print[ExplainedImpl](ExplainedImpl{})
    UncharteredPrint[UncharteredImpl, ExplainedImpl](UncharteredImpl{}) -> cannot infer PT (prog.go:36:37)
}
```

**Any idea what I'm doing wrong?** Seems like it should be possible but I'm unsure of what I'm missing here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the interface `UncharteredGeneric` is a parametrized *type*, you must explicitly supply all three type parameters.

Therefore in `UncharteredPrint` function type parameter list, `PT` should be:

```
PT UncharteredGeneric[T, U, V]
```

Now what is `V`? As seen in `UncharteredGeneric` own type param list, `V` must satisfy `ExplainedExampleGeneric[U]`, hence this is how we define it. The full signature becomes:

```
UncharteredPrint[T any, U any, V ExplainedExampleGeneric[U], PT UncharteredGeneric[T, U, V]](impl T)
```

You can't use directly `ExplainedExampleGeneric[U]` to instantiate `UncharteredGeneric` because `ExplainedExampleGeneric` includes the type element `*T`; you can only use it as a constraint for `V`.

Finally, after all this `PT` would be inferred as `*UncharteredImpl`, but this doesn't yet implement `UncharteredGeneric` — `V` is instantiated with `*ExplainedImpl`, but the method is declared as `GetExplainedExampleGeneric() ExplainedImpl`. You have also to fix the method signature to return the pointer type:

```
func (e *UncharteredImpl) GetExplainedExampleGeneric() *ExplainedImpl { return &ExplainedImpl{} }
```

Then, it compiles and runs: https://go.dev/play/p/zCZd53ys-5J